# Best practice MLR vs GLM(M)

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, multilevel-analysis, ecology

I am modelling timeseries of organism traits (7 different traits in total) using GLM(M)s in R. The data was collected at very irregular intervals and from 6 different locations. For every location 5-10 animals were sampled and some locations have been sampled multiple times whereas others just once or twice.
I am interested to see if *Trait* significantly changes with *Year*.

I decided to use Location as a random variable so that the model is of the form:

```
glmer(Trait~ Year + Var1 + (1|Location), 
               family=gaussian(link = "log"),
               data = data)
```

The model diagnostics lock good and don't give any reasons for concerns to me.

I did just for the sake of it model the same traits using multiple linear regression, this time having *Location* as a fixed term. This required the log transformation of *Traits*

```
lm(log(Trait) ~ Year + Var1 + Location, data = data)
```

Also for these models the diagnostics look good.
Both models suggest the same trend in the data.

Now the problem that I am facing is decide what model I should use? In the literature it is commonly mentioned that the simplest possible statistical tool should be favored over more complicated ones which suggests to me I should favor the linear regression but one is also discouraged to transform data to fit the model.

Comment: How many locations do you have?

Comment: 6 different locations

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a model with a transformed response & with a link function for the mean (see: [Why is GLM different than an LM with transformed variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122103/7290)).  These can't both be right.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica is quite right. I have updated my answer. You need to be consistent in what you are modelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

6 is considered to be at or very near the lower limit for fitting random intercepts. In your case I would suggest the linear model with fixed effects for location. If this is for publication / presentation then I would also mention that you have fitted a mixed model with random intercepts for location, and found that the inferences were very similar.

Also, note that, to be consisent, you should fit the models:

```
glm(Trait ~ Year + Var1 + Location, family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = data)
```

and

```
glmer(Trait ~ Year + Var1 + (1|Location),family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = data)
```

OR,

```
lm(log(Trait) ~ Year + Var1 + Location, data = data)
```

and

```
lmer(log(Trait) ~ Year + Var1 + (1|Location), data = data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is great.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help !