# Difference between specifying link function in GLM and transforming y data in advance?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, data-transformation, link-function

I'm a beginner in stats and I have a very basis question on GLM.

Suppose Gaussian distribution. GLM tries to do this:

$$g(E(y|X))=X\beta$$

where $g$ is a link function.

But if I transform $y$ before regression:

$$y'=g(y)$$

and do this:

$$E(y'|X)=X\beta$$

now this is an ordinary linear regression.

So my question is how are these two operations different with each other?

Comment: Many similar questions were asked (Look through the **Related** list in the right sidepanel), for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122103/why-is-glm-different-than-an-lm-with-transformed-variable  or [this stored search](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=transform+the+response+or+use+a+generalized+linear+model%3F++++site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Very much thanks! I haven't found those questions, and I'll flag this as duplicate!